# Typescript namespace undefined when referenced in a file

Tags: typescript

```
declare namespace Space.NewSpace {
    enum TestEnum {
        Foo,
        Bar
    }
}
```

in my `.tsx` file I'm trying to use the enum as follows:

```
Space.NewSpace.TestEnum.Foo
```

But it's throwing this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Space' of undefined`

Comment: Try getting rid of `declare`? Unless you're importing the namespace from somewhere else?

Comment: If I remove it, it says `Top-level declarations in .d.ts files must start with either a 'declare' or 'export' modifier.`

Answer (score 3):

Your `TypeError` is a JavaScript runtime error and not (directly) related to TS type system.

When you use `declare namespace`, you expect a third party library script to provide the namespace/property on the global namespace for you at runtime. `declare xxx` keyword is only relevant for compile type, e.g. to make global variables known for TS compiler. If there is no global property provided later on, you get above error.

So, if you have a third party namespace you depend on, you'll want to write:

```
declare namespace Space.NewSpace {
  enum TestEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar
  }
}
```

... and the library would provide the namespace similar to this:

```
var Space = {
  NewSpace: {
    // enum simplified here
    TestEnum: {"0": "Foo", "1": "Bar", Foo: 0, Bar: 1}
  }
};
```

If you write a namespace for your own code, leave out the `declare` keyword and export the members.

```
namespace Space.NewSpace {
  export enum TestEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar
  }
}

console.log(Space.NewSpace.TestEnum[0]); // Foo
```

Comment: removing declare throws this error: `Top-level declarations in .d.ts files must start with either a 'declare' or 'export' modifier.`

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty ...because you have to use declare, when you want to define an ambient (without implementation) namespace in a .d.ts file. Does this [sample repo](https://github.com/ford04/ts-namespace-sample) help?

Comment: ah so you're saying if i have a namespace with implementation (like my original post), it can't have the declare keyword? in that case do i need the actual implementation in another namespace (minus declare keyword)?

Comment: yes. and in this case, just write the implementation (`namespace` xxx) and drop the declaration (`declare namespace xxx`) entirely.